# C malloc/free corruption general questions

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

This question is similar to [c malloc questions (mem corruption)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639095/c-malloc-questions-mem-corruption) but I ask it again because I want more specific information than what was provided.

So I have a program with one malloc, followed by some complex code, followed by one free. Somewhere in the complex code, memory gets corrupted by either a double-free or an out-of-bounds write (both in separate regions of memory from the original malloc). This causes the original free to fail. This behaviour is fairly deterministic.

My questions are several:

1. What are the minimal conditions for a memory corruption to affect a separate memory region like this.
2. Are there any proactive steps that can be taken to prevent this cross-corruption.
3. Is it defined behaviour wrt standards to use pointer arithmetic to jump back and forth between contiguously allocated memory.

   ```
   /* 3 example */
   void *m = malloc(sizeof(header_struct) + sizeof(body_struct));
   body_struct *b = (body_struct*) (((header_struct*)m)+1);
   header_struct *h = (header_struct*) (((header_struct*)b)-1);
   ```

Comment: Your example doesn't take into account possible alignment requirements.  If alignment isn't an issue, then that code is ok (albeit somewhat strange).

Comment: pointer arithmetic is only defined within one object, like i.e. the block returned by a call to `malloc`. It does not matter whether two unrelated objects get allocated next to each other. If two objects are sub-objects of a bigger one, that's fine.

Comment: Look into a debugging malloc which can often be used to help catch problems.  To be somewhat more proactive, use the debugging malloc when you're testing also, to catch problems that might not always be so deterministic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good questions.

Q1. The minimal conditions **under the standard** are anything that triggers Undefined Behaviour. Unfortunately, that's a rather long list and not actionable. In practice the list comes down to 4 common scenarios: object underflow, object overflow, dangling reference or wild store.

Object underflow happens when you write to bytes just before the allocated block. It is very common for those bytes to contain critical block links and the damage is usually severe.

Object overflow happens when you write to bytes just after the allocated block. There is usually a small a amount of padding at the end so a byte or two will usually do no serious damage. If you keep writing you will eventually hit something important, as per underflow.

Dangling reference means writing via a pointer that used to be valid. It could be a pointer to a local variable that has gone out of scope, or to a block that has been freed. These are nasty.

Wild store means writing to an address way outside an allocated block. That could be a small positive address (say pointer value of 0x20) and in a debug environment these areas can often be protected, or it can be random garbage because the pointer itself got damaged. These are less common, but very hard to find and fix.

Q2. A debug heap is your first level of protection. It will check the links and write special patterns into unused space and generally help to find and fix problems. if you are using a debug heap then free() usually triggers some diagnostic activities, but you can usually find some other call to do the same thing. On Windows that is HeapValidate().

You can do more by implementing your own heap with guards/sentinels (look that up) and your own heap checking functions. Beyond that (in C at least), you just have to get better at writing the code. You can add assertions so at least the code fails fast.

Then you can use external tools. One is valgrnd, but it is not always feasible. In one case we wrote a complete heap logging system to track every allocation, to find problems like these.

Q3. Your second example does not guarantee the correct alignment of `body_struct` in line 2. According to the C standard n1570 S7.22.3, memory returned by `malloc()` is suitable aligned to be used as a pointer to any object. The compiler will lay out the structs with this assumption.

However, that requirement does not extend to the members of an array of structs. It is implementation-defined whether the second member of an array of a struct like this is aligned or not.

```
struct s {
  double d;
  char c;
} ss[2];
```

With this in mind, your code is valid C, but may have implementation-defined or Undefined Behaviour, depending on alignment requirements. It is certainly not recommended.

Comment: I think that bit you quoted from the standard only requires that alignment requirements of the pointers themselves be the same.

Comment: @RossRidge: Oops. The start of the struct is OK, but the end is not. See edit.

Comment: As a Point of Order, N1570 is a Committee Draft of ISO/IEC 9899:201x and I would advise caution before citing paragraphs from this, and assuming they are the same in the final (published)  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Standard!

Comment: @Andrew: I'm aware of the issue but I don't think there is any choice. AFAIK the published standard is not available for linking, only for purchase. I think this does the industry a serious disservice, and if the final is significantly different that would compound the harm done. Fortunately it usually is not.

Comment: Agreed in all respects, David.  That is one of the pitfalls of the ISO (and MISRA) business models.  But I regularly see people citing ISO CD 26262 (or DIS or FDIS) which are HUGELY different from the published document :(

Answer (score 0):

(1) Any undefined behaviour can cause such memory corruption, including but not restricted to writing to any memory location that is not part of an object.

(2) Write your code carefully :-(

(3) The second assignment is not portable and can lead to all kinds of problems due to alignment problems. To make this correct and portable, you usually use a flexible array member. If you always allocate one header and one body, define a new struct

```
typedef struct {
    header_struct header;
    body_struct body;
} body_plus_header_struct;
```

If you allocate one header and a variable number of bodies, write

```
typedef struct {
    header_struct header;
    body_struct bodies [];
} body_plus_header_struct;
```

Here, body_plus_header_struct has a size that is guaranteed to be rounded up so that the address of the bodies array has the correct alignment. To allocate a struct for n bodies, allocate

```
body_plus_header_struct* p = malloc (sizeof (*p) + n * sizeof (p->bodies [0]));
```